# Why is this Redux state being mutated?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am having a problem with prevProps and this.props evaluating as different, despite the structures visually looking the same. I am assuming it is something to do with the arrays, however even after stripping out any changes to the existing state in my reducer, the problem still persists. Within 'Settings' there is an array, but since I am not mutating anything here, I don't see why the comparison would fail in my react component,

```
case types.UPDATE_USER_SETTINGS_SUCCESS: {
    return {
        ...state,
        user: {
            ...state.user,
            settings: {
                ...state.user.settings,
            },
        },
    };
}
```

This is the code that I am then using to compare the state in UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps.

```
if (this.props.user.settings !== nextProps.user.settings) {
        console.log('is different');
    }
```

The console log is firing each time and I cannot work out why. Dev tools shows the same objects.

(I realise the reducer code won't actually change anything, but I have removed the action payload for now to demonstrate that I am still getting the same problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly you have "is different" in the console log after the `UPDATE_USER_SETTINGS_SUCCESS` action is fired.

This is to be expected since you are mutating the state. In your reducer you write:

```
settings: {
   ...state.user.settings,
}
```

That means that you do in fact get a new object. This line does not seem to do anything though, so if you remove it, then it should work as expected. Note: you do not need to remove the whole reducer, because even though you do return a new state with some of the fields referencing new objects, if you remove settings spread you will get exactly the same reference to the `settings`.

P.S. The whole reducer is not doing anything as far as I can see apart from returning a different object for some of the fields. The values are identical, but the references are not so you will get `!==` to be true.

Comment: Thanks. This helped me realise what I was doing wrong. I don't compare the objects anywhere else in the app so must have been having a dumb moment. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

They always will differ because you make [shallow comparison](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/is) of object references:

```
// Always true in javascript
{ a: 1 } !== { a: 1 }
```

That's because you return a new object in the reducer:

```
case types.UPDATE_USER_SETTINGS_SUCCESS: {
    // Thats a new object reference
    return { /* state */},
    };
}
```